# Uninstall Docker

Tags: software-installation, docker

I have installed docker as described here [raspberrypi.org/blog/docker-comes-to-raspberry-pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/docker-comes-to-raspberry-pi/) with `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh`.
How do I uninstall it?

Comment: For posterity, this is the wrong way to install now that docker is in the Raspbian repos.

Comment: That doesn't help now does it...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had to use `sudo apt remove docker-ce`. The script at [get.docker.com](https://get.docker.com/) runs `"$pkg_manager install -y -q docker-ce$pkg_version"` so `docker-ce` is the package, not `docker`.

Comment: "docker -v" still worked. I did "sudo apt autoremove" to get rid of it entirely.

Comment: You also want to uninstall `docker-ce-cli`.

Answer (score 6):

Uninstall it by using

```
apt remove docker -y
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Worth noting that the script sourced by `curl | sh` appears to use `apt-get`, which is why `apt remove` is appropriate.

Comment: Does that work when docker was not installed with apt?

Comment: It does not: "Package 'docker' is not installed, so not removed"

Comment: Well, it very well *could* have, if you go look at it.  What it does if it didn't will be harder to figure out.  You might check `dpkg -l | grep docker` to see if it used a package with a more convoluted name.

Comment: After that I did `sudo dpkg --purge docker-ce`

Answer (score 6):

To remove the package:
`sudo apt remove docker-ce*`

To remove the docker0 network interface:
`sudo ip link delete docker0`

Comment: Thanks. This also removed docker-ce-cli to on my pi 3.

Answer (score 2):

Additional:
Remove any USB Ethernet entries that you might have put at the bottom of the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`

why?
I upgraded to buster stable and my RPi3B+ seemed like it was fire-walled. Above fixes ethernet ghosted connections,  WIFI was working. I say ghosted because the Plymouth desktop showed a live connected eth0 and Ip address, for example, 192.168.1.100 but couldn't ping anything local to remote and vice versa. If I locally clicked on the WiCD icon the network would come alive. But not on a reboot.

The residue of Docker USB-net connections to the swarm, in the dhcpd, was stopping me using the ethernet.

Comment: Also, when doing apt-update, docker.com was still in the sources.list . To remove the entry  $ sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list